# Python Linked List with Nodes. Iterable

Tags: python, linked-list, listiterator

I need some help writing an `__iter__()` method for my `UnorderedList()` class. I tried this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    current = self
    while current != None:
        yield current
```

But the `while` loop doesn't stop. Here is the rest of my classes and code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

    def getData(self):
        return self.data

    def getNext(self):
        return self.next

    def setData(self,newdata):
        self.data = newdata

    def setNext(self,newnext):
        self.next = newnext

class UnorderedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0
```

Comment: Why *would* it stop?  You set `current` to the instance `self` then repeatedly `yield` it. Nothing *changes* inside the loop, so logically it must never start or never end. Also, note that you should test identity for `None`; `while current is not None:`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to iterate all items succeedingly, you should do

```
def __iter__(self):
    # Remember, self is our UnorderedList.
    # In order to get to the first Node, we must do
    current = self.head
    # and then, until we have reached the end:
    while current is not None:
        yield current
        # in order to get from one Node to the next one:
        current = current.next
```

so that in every step you go one step further.

BTW, setters and getters aren't used in Python in the form of methods. If you need them, use properties, otherwise omit them altogether.

So just do

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, initdata):
        self.data = initdata
        self.next = None

class UnorderedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        current = self.head
        while current is not None:
            yield current
            current = current.next
```

Comment: I tried that but it gives an Attribute error: UnorderedList object has no attribute 'next'.

Comment: @Newbie Did you notice my edit? Also, if someone gives you code which has minor errors, you should be able to find them on your own. If a `UnorderedList` has no `next`, but a `head`, you sould refer to that, of course. The next steps, from one node to the next, happens with `.next`.

Comment: I did some more research and realized this was a dumb question sorry. Thanks for explaining.